# Is it possible to remotely connect to computer without disrupting their session?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, remote-desktop, virtualization, vnc

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to connect to a computer using RDP, VNC, Etc without actually disrupting the computer you are logging into.

My wife uses my desktop computer at home so she can get work done while I am at work, and alot of time I need to access that computer to get either files or use a specific application etc. So basically whenever I login to it I hijack it from her.

So this leads me to ask is their any way I can access an application on the computer without interfering with her activities? Sometimes I need to login with a linux box or mac as well so I am not sure if the new App Virtualization methods will work.

Comment: Windows Server has this capability none of the home user versions of Windows gives you this ability nor right through a license.

Comment: Does it allow you to access them through macs and linux aswell or only other Windows pcs? I am guessing this is Virtual application streaming, so I am geussing it's not possible. Thank you for the information.

Comment: You could remote desktop into a virtual machine that is running on the  computer without taking over the whole computer.

Comment: I thought about that but I wouldnt have access to any of my applications or files since it would have to be a fresh install? Unless I am wrong and their is another way.

Comment: Which version and edition (home, pro, etc.) of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Professional.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent desktop sessions are limited to server editions of windows. There are [hacks](http://www.techspot.com/guides/485-windows-concurrent-sessions/) available... but I would be very cautious of them.

You don't have this restriction on linux. If the programs you need happen to have a linux version or run under [wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), then you could set up a linux system for concurrent desktop sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a file you can use Teamviewer.  It has a built in file transfer that takes place without hijacking the mouse.  However the screen will flash when  you connect and a notification appears in the lower right corner.  This application will also allow to you access applications but if you use it for remote support rather then file management you would take control of the keyboard and mouse from her.  This will not log her off, and she would not lose any work, but you would be in control of the PC at the time you logged in.

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For accessing remote files, I've had great success using [Logmein Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/). It creates a VPN and any files you share on your home computer will be available to any other computer you attach to the same VPN (e.g., your office computer). This gives you access to all the files as if they were available locally or on your LAN.

For running an application at home - sorry, Hamachi doesn't give you that - but you can access executable files remotely to run on your local computer (assuming they don't require special installation or configuration options, such as registry changes, etc.)